# Inserting Multiple spaces in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am trying to insert multiple spaces between two words in jsp.

Is there a way to insert spaces without using `&emsp;&emsp;` mulitple times?

Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please give your code snippet?

Answer (score 5):

In short, no.

HTML defines that sequences of multiple spaces have the same significance as a single space.  There is also the non-breaking space, represented by the character entity `&nbsp;`.  Do note that using spaces is not a good method for achieving layout and alignment (if that is your actual goal).

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html

> For all HTML elements except PRE, **sequences** of white space separate "words"

*(empahsis mine)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.So how will this be achieved.I am trying to get multiple spaces between Help and Logout 2 hyperlinks which are in the same row but Logout option has to be at the right end.Can you suggest something else to achieve this goal?

Comment: Use CSS to define the padding (and/or margin) and placement of those two elements.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose it in a `<pre>` tag. 
Example:

```
out.println("<pre>This text has   multiple      spaces </pre>");
```

You can use it whenever you need unusual formatting. Look at the link [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) for more details about the tag

Comment: `out.println` in jsp ??? although jsp is converted internally to servlet which uses `out.println` but the question seeks answer with regards to jsp.

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally considered wise to stick a ton of nbsp's in your HTML, as the spacing is a formatting concern, rather than a semantic component of the HTML or the data, itself.

Instead, I usually try to use CSS to format things like that:

```
.spacey { word-spacing: 20px; }

<p class="spacey">This is some text with 20 pixels between each word.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the JSP of your choice do the following at the bottom

```
<%!
public String getSpaces(int numSpaces)
{
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(numSpaces);
  for(int i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++)
    buffer.append(" ");
  return buffer.toString();
}
%>
```

Then where you want space

```
This will have lot of spaces <%= getSpaces(10)%> here
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am using Struts2 framework.I have implemented Action class.Shall I implement the function in the action class?

Comment: When I try implementing the function I get org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/create_corpus.jsp(5,1) Page directive: illegal to have multiple occurrences of language with different values (old: java, new: Java) error.

Comment: StringBuilder buffer = new Buffer(numSpaces); how is this possible? I tried it doesnt work..